# how can use .AS files code into a .FLA file?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

how can i use the code in a .AS file in a .FLA file without merging them together so basically in the .AS file the code is in a package how can i remove the package and use that same code in my .FLA without importing .AS file

Comment: It would really help to understand what do you want if you add some punctuation to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use methods from the class as frame actions: You need to copy and edit the code to remove all references to class specific variables or methods, or replace those with references available on the main timeline.

But why would you want to mix your AS code into the FLA if you have it cleanly separated already? Clean separation is something you *want*, so you should rather think about how your project is set up and how you could use the class files in a clean OO way - it will help making your code elements reusable and easier to debug.

Comment: thanks but i preffer to use the code direct in the fla instead of import plus the code is not alot

Comment: Suit yourself - then the first paragraph will apply.